# Cilick on table visualization row and highlight Spotfire action control button

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I have a table visualization in my Spotfire dashboard, which shows up all the required values. I have a Spotfire button in a text area, which picks the values from the selected row in my table.

I want to highlight the button whenever I click on the rows of my table visualization.
Any suggestions on how I can add any onclick function to my table visualization, to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to trigger an IronPython script on a click of a column in a table visualisation ?

I guess in the the graphical table there is an "Action" which can be configured to trigger the IP script.

And you could also mark the row and pass it as in input to the datafunction  which in turn updates a Doc prop and triggers the IP script.

Comment: Yes, I want to trigger an Iron Python script on-click of a row in a table visualization. I didn't find the Action option which you mentioned in the case of table visualization, unlike KPI tiles. Moreover, I want to trigger the script to change the background color of a button in a separate text area.   But, I'll try out the Socument property workaround you mentioned.

Comment: You can trigger a  Data Function on a Marking event.  Update a document property in the data finction, with some data which will inturn trigger the IronPython script.